# JavaFX - Different css classes for same node types

Tags: css, javafx

I am trying to assign two different styles to the same type of node of a JavaFX application.

For example, suppose I have two Text nodes

```
<Text text="Welcome" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" 
        GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
<Text text="Goodbye" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" 
        GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
```

and an application.css

```
Text {
    -fx-font-size: 15pt;
    -fx-font-family: Tahoma;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

This way, I will style both texts with the same class. How can I create and assign two different styles to the two instances of Text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `id` attribute, to differentiate the two `Text` nodes and apply different CSS on them

```
<Text text="Welcome" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" 
        GridPane.rowIndex="0" id="text1"/>
<Text text="Goodbye" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" 
        GridPane.rowIndex="0" id="text2"/>
```

and in the css file, you can have

```
#text1{
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
    -fx-font-family: Tahoma;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

#text2{
        -fx-font-size: 15pt;
        -fx-font-family: Tahoma;
        -fx-font-weight: regular;
}
```

**P.S.** You can also separate the same using different css class for the two texts. Please follow [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm) for more information